# Pause html video when going out of viewport reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

I am developing a `ReactJs` application where I use html video player to play videos. I have a requirement where the video needs to be paused when it goes out of view port or when another video comes into the view port and starts playing. I referred many examples but most of them says how to do it using external libraries or using `jQuery`.

```
<video controls autoPlay loop muted controlsList='nodownload' poster={this.props.postData.media[0].thumbnail}>
    <source src={this.props.postData.media[0].sourcePath} type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

This is my code for video player. I read somewhere that `onBlur` event can be used to implement this. But that didn't work unfortunately. May be because I was not doing it right. I want something similar to what Twitter and LinkedIn does.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is interested in a solution for this, I managed to get it working using a custom hook. It is kinda ugly but it gets the job done.

```
export function useVideoAutoplay({ threshold = 0.8 } = {}) {
  function checkScroll() {
    const videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

    for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
      const video = videos[i];

      const x = video.offsetLeft;
      const y = video.offsetTop;
      const w = video.offsetWidth;
      const h = video.offsetHeight;
      const r = x + w; // right
      const b = y + h; // bottom

      const visibleX = Math.max(
        0,
        Math.min(
          w,
          window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x,
          r - window.pageXOffset,
        ),
      );
      const visibleY = Math.max(
        0,
        Math.min(
          h,
          window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y,
          b - window.pageYOffset,
        ),
      );

      const visible = (visibleX * visibleY) / (w * h);

      if (visible > threshold) {
        video.play();
      } else {
        video.pause();
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
      window.removeEventListener('resize', checkScroll);
    };
  }, []);
}
```

In App.js then just:

```
useVideoAutoplay();
```